# Fill space between two static size divs

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` element (`1200px` width) that contains 3 inner `divs`.
First and last ones have static sizes (`150px` and `200px`). I want the second one to be centered between logo and buttons. The problem is I don't know how to center this `div`...

```css
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: grey;
}
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: darkred;
}
.text {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
.buttons {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="text">SOME CENTERED TEXT HERE</div>
  <div class="buttons"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach would be to set the `display` of the `.text` element to `inline-block` (and remove `float: left`), then add `text-align: center` to the parent element in order to center it. Since the other elements are floated, `text-align` won't affect them, and it will only center the inline `.text` element.

```css
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: darkred;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
}
.buttons {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="text">SOME CENTERED TEXT HERE</div>
  <div class="buttons"></div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also add `margin: auto` to the `.text` element and then set `display: flex` on the parent element. In doing so, the `.text` element will be centered horizontally with equal space on each side. In doing so, you don't need to float the elements either (since they are flexbox items).

```css
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
}
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkred;
}
.text {
  margin: auto;
}
.buttons {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="text">SOME CENTERED TEXT HERE</div>
  <div class="buttons"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're floating the centre column. Don't.
The proper way to do what you're doing is to put the left and right columns first, then the centre column won't have to float and you can simply use `text-align`.

```css
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: grey;
}
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: darkred;
}
.text {
  text-align:center;
}
.buttons {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="buttons"></div>
  <div class="text">SOME CENTERED TEXT HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Technically, in your example, the element `.text` isn't centered (only the text is). Try adding a background-color to the element, and it will demonstrate that the element has a width of `100%` still. Of course, this may be what the OP wants, I'm just pointing that out..

Comment: @JoshCrozier Right. So I should have said "one way to solve this" instead of "the proper way"! Oh well. Let the OP decide.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.text {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trivial with Flexbox:

```css
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: grey;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: darkred;
}
.text {
  background:#c0ffee
  }
.buttons {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="text">SOME CENTERED TEXT HERE</div>
  <div class="buttons"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an (I think) more appropriate solution which **centers the entire** `div` and **not only the text**, using `width:calc(100% - 350px);`

https://jsfiddle.net/tyvfcbre/1/

```
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  width:calc(100% - 350px);
  background:lightgrey;
}
```

Background is there to demonstrate the `div` position.